# Looping an API using NiFi with different URLs

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm a freshman using NiFi. I have the following NiFi dataflow getting data from GET request on a fixed URL, but my endpoint has a set of parameters to fetch parts of the data, for example the page id. I want to avoid making this same workflow for a slightly different request URL.

In the API, I can request for the list of pages available, and I want to use the result of such request to start looping the workflow below. How would I do this??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your easiest way to do this would be to add expression language statements to parameterize the URL in `InvokeHTTP` and then put `ExecuteScript` ([Cookbook](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922)) above it with a Groovy or JRuby (don't use Jython!) script to generate flowfiles that have attributes that correspond to the parameter names.

This is a simple script that would generate a request for each page for a url with a parameter called tag:

```
def pages = 10

1.upto(pages) { page ->
  def ff = session.create();
  ff = session.putAttribute(ff, "tag", "articles")
  ff = session.putAttribute(ff, "page", page.toString())
  session.transfer(ff, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

The attributes are then visible with expression language as `${tag}` and `${page}`. See documentation for more complex scripting examples. You'll want to make sure that `InvokeHTTP` is set to write the REST response to the body of the flowfile (that's a configuration option).

Comment: Many thanks, it worked. But why not use jython? Actually, in my processor there's the option for python, but I suppose they refer to the same language, am I right?

Comment: The "python" option is actually the Jython script engine, that's just how it reports its name. Jython is much slower than languages like Groovy and Javascript/Nashorn, and has concurrency issues and known bugs that can make it difficult to deal with.